Shelf not lining up with holes in floating rod
I bought two used floating shelves and just hung them up on my wall. For some reason, the screws that go through the bottom of the shelf are not aligning with the metal holes in the floating rods for 3 of 4 spots. And not just by a little—they are off by 1/2 cm. I know because my screws left a little nick in the rods' metal.
What should I do? Since it's so staggered, I wanted to drill a hole into the rods where the nicks are, but I'm not super knowledgeable about hardware so idk how to do that. The brackets nor shelves are flush to the wall or bracket respectively, which is why I feel I should drill a new hole rather than try to force them to align (because with the uneven wall, they won't).
I was thinking about getting screws that could go through sheet metal, but sheet metal is likely more brittle than these rods.
24 hours later, I'm also thinking maybe I should drill new, better aligned holes in the shelf rather than the metal. But then that risks overlapping with the current holes (weak points) in the shelf already...
Red arrow holes not aligning with yellow arrow holes:






You said you bought two shelves, try switching the shelf part with the other one to see if it matches.

In what direction are they misaligned? Is the problem that the shelf won't go on far enough, or that the shelf would be off the wall with the holes aligned? Please revise again to add clarity around that. (Don't say it down here.)

When you slide the shelf onto the rods is it up tight to the wall and fully parallel with the wall and back of the bracket? An uneven wall could prevent alignment of the holes.

@JACK unfortunately one is 3 ft and the other is 2 ft so they won't fit each others brackets

@MichaelKaras I think that's def the problem—the bracket against the wall nor the shelf against the bracket sits flush. I think the wall must be uneven because I have the bracket level. That's why I'm wondering if I should just drill additional holes in the bracket, since they will not align even with force (me pushing the shelf as close to the wall as possible). https://imgur.com/a/XzyBir9  (I'm sorry idk how to embed images on here so I keep having to upload externally)

@Anna - I see two issues from the added pictures. (1) The wall is indeed uneven although some of that may be distortion in the camera image. (2) Use of the round head screws is probably part of the problem. Flat head screws of the appropriate size could pull part way into the bracket hole allowing the shelf to slide in closer to the flat part of the bracket.
